# "python -m pip install pynput" VS "pip install pynput"

Tags: python, pip

I first tried

```
pip install pynput
```

Then I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pynput (from versions: none) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pynput
```

Then I tried:

```
python -m pip install pynput
```

Then I got this:

```
Installing collected packages: python-xlib, pynput
Successfully installed pynput-1.5.0 python-xlib-0.25
```

So **what is difference between "python -m pip install pynput" and  "pip install pynput"?** I do this inside a conda environment, which has python 2.7 in it

Comment: This question is probably being down-voted because it isn't clear that it relates to Ubuntu as opposed to Python, Pip, or Conda.  I suggest researching this question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python and asking there if you cannot find a suitable answer.

As an aside, looks like you are invoking a version of pip with the first command that is not available to the environment you are in (python 2.7).  The unix `which` command by be helpful to distinguish (`which python` and `which pip` in the directory you are working in).

Answer (score 0):

There is no different. pip is a python modul. Python allows you to start modules directly from shell because it is creating files in /usr/local/bin/pip. You run the same program.